# how to determine what pan view is in what index

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an app with 3 uiimageviews on the screen. each one has a uipangesture connected to it. I am having trouble determining which pan view goes to which box. (see image below.) The white boxes determine if a pan view is in them by CGRectContainsPoint(). My main problem is getting the text out of the labels that are in the image views. Since they will always be different, how can I know from a 1, 2, 3 kind of indexing which pan's view is in which box?

Here is my code.

```
    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        ++_countSoFar;   // _countSoFar is an iVar

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.view1.frame, pan.view.center)) {
            pan.view.tag = 1;
        }
        else if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.view2.frame, pan.view.center)) {
            pan.view.tag = 2;
        }
        else pan.view.tag = 3;

        NSLog(@"counts = %d", _countSoFar);
    }
    if (_countSoFar == carLevels)
    {

        NSString *s1 = [[self.view viewWithTag:pan.view.tag].subviews[0] text];

        _countSoFar = 0;  //reset count
    }
```

The problem with my code is I can only get 1 text value because the subviews only has 1 per view...I can't figure this out. Any help will be appreciated!

Here is the image:

[image: iimage]

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Set the property of UIImageView and on the gesture recongnizer event handler, get the attached UIImageView and identify the relevant content based on the index you set.
2. Subclass the UIPanGestureRecognizer, add a new field called index and use that to capture the gestures and then the index from that

Comment: ok, well which one would you say is the easiest to probably perform?

Comment: ok. So when I am finishing up each pan gesture, I would check if the pan.view is UIImageView, and if it is, then I would set the tag of it to be whatever index?